# Block level elements after left floating elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

```css
.redBox {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.blueBox {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="redBox"></div>
  <!--<div class="blueBox"></div>-->
  <p>Hello</p>
</body>
```

I'm trying to understand how float+clear works. My understanding is, unless you set clear on the block level element following the floating element, its going to end up starting from the top left. We see that if you un-comment bluebox div. My question is why dont see see this behaviour in the block level element p? Why does that not begin behind the div?

Comment: Right click on hello and select inspect.

Comment: Cool. Looks like the p element is starting from the top left. Then a follow up question is how does it shift automatically to the right of the red box? Is this an HTML rendering feature?

Comment: You can read about the mechanics of floats here (steps 1-9): https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats

Comment: @j08691 why don't you answer the question so i can choose it?

Comment: I don't have much of an answer for you other than the documentation I pointed you to.